# can ehcache-replicated.xml be placed outside of WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java, tomcat, ehcache, cas

I am trying to create an environment where the application build remains same across environments. To support this I've externalized any property files to be read from an external directory e.g.$CATALINA_BASE/conf/app1/config

We use ehcache for caching (for CAS) and for replication between instances I seem to get the errror if the ehcache-replicated.xml is not present in the WEB-INF/classes directory. I've tried updating the setenv.sh of Tomcat so:

```
CLASSPATH=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/app1/config/ehcache-replicated.xml
export CLASSPATH
```

I also tried adding to JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A classpath entry is a directory, not a file. So try `CLASSPATH=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/app1/config`, it might work.

I am saying might because Tomcat is applying class loader isolation. A war won't see the classpath of the application server. So, it depends where you are setting the classpath.

In general, adding the classpath entry in `catalina.properties` `shared.loader` works. But that's from the top of my head.